# Как подключить random org на сайт?

Tags: случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Я хочу подключить на свой сайт random org скрипт для генерации чисел. У них на сайте есть описание API, но я не могу разобраться, как оно работает. Может кто нибудь может растолковать, как это работает. Заранее спасибо

Comment: `random` можно и на `php` взять, зачем `api`

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы пользователи видели, что это реально рандомное число, и если что могли перейти на random.org и проверить это на этой страничке https://api.random.org/verify

Comment: В чем проблема генерировать числа пока нужное не попадется? Наверное долго

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вам надо [получить ключ](https://api.random.org/api-keys/beta) доступа к **API**
2. После этого вы должны выполнить **POST** запрос на адрес https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke с заголовком `content-type: application/json` и передать **JSON** объект

   ```
   {
       "jsonrpc": "2.0",
       "method": "generateIntegers",
       "params": {
           "apiKey": "ваш ключ",
           "n": 10,
           "min": 1,
           "max": 123456789,
           "replacement": true
       },
       "id": 3
   }
   ```

   Где:

   - **method** - метод который вы хотите выполнить
   - **apiKey** - ваш ключ
   - **id** - уникальный идентификатор запроса и ответа
   - **params** - параметры для метода (они могут отличатся для разных методов)

   И в ответ вы получите

   ```
   {
       "jsonrpc": "2.0",
       "result": {
           "random": {
               "data": [
                   47209387,
                   29112205,
                   67652257,
                   25567818,
                   74065963,
                   19777276,
                   45858504,
                   122833666,
                   11524610,
                   10283904
               ],
               "completionTime": "2017-06-13 14:29:04Z"
           },
           "bitsUsed": 269,
           "bitsLeft": 249725,
           "requestsLeft": 997,
           "advisoryDelay": 180
       },
       "id": 3
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо! А я все не мог понять, как это работает

Comment: А как отправить файл json из php можете подсказать?

Comment: @Daniel217 curl это умеет.